# ExpandableList with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, expandablelistview

All the examples that I see about ExpandableList are with strings. I need to make an ExpandableList that when you open for example the first group item there appears a google maps map and when I open the second one there appears a conversation between two users (stored in the DB) It can be possible?
I only know how work the structure to appear another list into the group item. How can I do the structure to make there appear different things like a map of google maps?